# Custom Colors in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can we add custom colors (HEX or RGB) to a SXSSFWorkbook? I found multiple implementations where everyone used HSSFPalette to change the custom palette of a HSSFWorkbook. But unlike HSSFWorkbook, SXSSFWorkbook doesn't have a getCustomPalette call and therefore I couldn't get any palette to override. Any pointers?

Comment: please refer to this link. 
a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561710/using-custom-colors-with-sxssf-apache-poi

Answer (score 7):

An `SXSSFWorkbook` is a wrapper around a `XSSFWorkbook`.  Because it's just `XSSF`, you can directly [create an `XSSFColor` with any RGB you want](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html).  You don't need to override any palette.

```
XSSFColor customColor = new XSSFColor(new byte[] {alpha, red, green, blue});
```

You can also pass a `java.awt.Color` if you want.

```
XSSFColor anotherColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(red, green, blue, alpha));
```