# How to set background color for merged cells in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image]

I use the following code to set background color for cells:

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) excelStyle.getCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.decode("#FFFF99")));
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

But it is not working for cells which are merged, it always becomes black no matter of what I try to set.
It is working only if I set a predefined color like:

```
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.CORAL.index);
```

The color is defined by user so I can't use `IndexedColors`. Also, I can't create a custom palette color (as explained [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors)) because my workbook is of type `SXSSFWorkbook`, not `HSSFWorkbook`.

How to set background color for merged cells?

Comment: When I do not know how to use Apache POI, I usually do the formatting in Excel and then look at the result XLSX file what is stored there. You can often guess what you should do in POI then :) Just rename XLSX to ZIP and look inside. Compare the formatting of unmerged and merged cells.

Comment: @HonzaZidek in style file I spoted some differences, but still can't say what's the problem https://pastebin.com/Nk1Xz9Dp

Comment: Have you tried all described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20561710/2886891 ?

Comment: @HonzaZidek, yes. It's actually what I'm doing now

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below steps and working for me.

1. Create a sheet
2. Create a row
3. Create style with custom colors using RGB values
4. Loop for creating cell > create cell and add value to cells 0 which will appear for subsequent merged cells, apply style to every cell,
5. Finally merge cells > lets say you want to merge cell 0 to cell 3 of row 0 use `sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 3));`

After lot of debugging I found issue which was causing the merged cell to be always black was below line.

```
CellUtil.setAlignment(sheetSummary.getRow(0).getCell(4), HorizontalAlignment.CENTER_SELECTION);
```